# How can I redirect $_GET variables onto another page?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, get

I've been having a problem with my Wordpress build which has a site url one layer up than the actual Wordpress directory. The problem is that any links from the Wordpress site automatically redirect themselves relative to the site url.

Let's say that I'm in Wordpress and I want to go to the link for `./blog/?p=1` (relative to the root directory), the only option that I am given is to go for `./?p=1`. I have looked around, and there isn't much help for such a problem.

So, I'd like to ask about an alternative... is there a way to redirect anyone if they have set any `$_GET` parameters at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all the attributes of _GET intact, you can run the url through a quick check which goes as follows:

```
if ( !empty($_GET) ) {
    $c = 0;
    foreach( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        $points[$c] = array( $key, $value );
        $c++;
    }
    $redirect = "./blog/?";
    $and = "";
    foreach( $points as $got ) {
        $redirect .= $and.$got[0]."=".$got[1];
        $and = "&";
    }
    header( "Location: ".$redirect );
}
```

This firstly checks whether or not there are any `$_GET` statements selected (you can add escape statements for taken attributes with an AND check) and then goes through the statement logically. Firstly, we store each point in a multi-dimensional array and increment that for as many iterations as we need to do.

From there, we can set up the redirect link. This is done by setting the base redirect and then adding on any `$_GET` items that were found in the order that they were found in.

The final step is to do the redirect, and then it is done.